# Books and online resources to get me started in the finite element method (FEM)

Tags: mathematical-modeling, mechanical-properties, finite-element-analysis

In a course on the mechanical properties of materials, I have been asked to do a paper on the "[Finite Element Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method)" to improve my current grade.

However, most of the resources I find on the Internet explain theoretical frameworks, with complex mathematics that I do not understand.

Do you know of any book or website that explains this method in a simple way? In short, that focuses, above all, on the applications for a materials engineer and that provides, if possible, a simple theoretical framework, which can be understood without the need for external help or almost impossible mathematics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here is a short video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6X9Ry02mPU) to explain the following points about FEM:

1. Why study FEM
2. Engineering systems and FEM
3. What is FEM?
4. Layman's explanation
5. Mathematical treatment
6. The power of FEM

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you to visit and go through the COMSOL Multiphysics [site](https://www.comsol.com/).

COMSOL software is based on finite element method (FEM) with applications in several areas of Physics. In the site, you can request a demonstration of the software (so you will have the experience to use FEM in practice) and also can visit the [WEBMINARS](https://www.comsol.com/events/webinars) section that is full of applications with very useful discussions.

Comment: By the way, do you know any free software? I have checked and my University doesn't have the license for the program. On the other hand, do you know any resource where I can understand, the basis of this method.

Comment: +1 to Camps! @aprendiendo-a-programar if you want to know about free software you have to ask a new question. Commemts are for clarifying missing details in an answer, not for asking new questions.